# Streaming Logs for Azure Function for local debugging VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

So where can one find the local logs for when debugging a Azure Function locally with Visual Studio 2019?

Relevent documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/streaming-logs

The Azure Function documentation only explains this for VS Code, but for this project I need VS 2019, and they are not where I would expect to find them (in the Output window under the Debug dropdown).
They can be seen on the deployed function fine in the Streaming logs, so they are getting created, but for development speed I need them locally too.

I have been looking and googling for a day or two now, so I am reluctantly resorting to Stack Overflow. They must be there somewhere, right?

Answer (score 1):

The logs should also appear in the console window when you start your project.

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't quite the answer, but it got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was I was using information level messages and they don't come to the console by default. There were some messages on the console, but I had no idea they were actually log messages, thanks to Justin for putting me on to this.

More googling revealed you need to specify an additional argument on startup to see those messages - in Visual Studio on the Properties dialog for the function app Project - a screenshot of that dialog:

[image]

Comment: I spent a while (minutes) trying to get that to work, trying several variations of it. Never occurred to me to prefix with _start_, so you've helped me back. Thanks.